# grep through a file conditionally in both directions

Tags: regex, grep

I have a log file written to by several instances of a cgi script. I need to extract certain information, with the following typical workflow:

1. search for the first occurrence of `RequestString`
2. extract PID from that log line
3. search backwards for the first occurrence of `PID<separator>ConnectionString`, to identify the client that initiated the request
4. do something with `ConnectionString` and repeat the search from after 'RequestString'

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking of writing a perl script to do this with caching the last `N` lines, and then match through those lines to perform 3.

Is there any better way to do this? Like extended regex that would do exactly this?

Sample with line numbers for reference -- not part of the file:

```
1 date    pid1    ConnectionString1
2 date    pid2    ConnectionString2
3 date    pid3    ConnectionString3
4 date    pid2    SomeOutput2
5 date    pid2    SomeOutput2
6 date    pid4    ConnectionString4
7 date    pid3    SomeOutput3
8 date    pid4    RequestString4
9 date    pid1    SomeOutput1
10 date    pid1    ConnectionString1
11 date    pid1    RequestString1
12 date    pid5    RequestString5
```

When I grep through this sample file, I wish for the following to match:

- line 8, paired with line 6
- line 11, paired with line 10 (and not with line 1)

Specifically, the following shouldn't be matched:

- line 12, because no matching ConnectionString with that pid is found (pid5)
- line 1, because there is a new ConnectionString for that pid before the next RequestString for that pid (line 10). Imagine that the first connection attempt failed before logging the RequestString)
- any of the lines from pid2/pid3, because hey dont have a RequestString logged.

I could imagine writing a regex with the option for . to match \n:`((pid\d)\s*(ConnectionString\d))(?!\1).*\2\s*RequestString\d` and then use `\3` to identify the client.

However, there are disproportionately more (perhaps between 1000 and 10000 times more) `ConnectionString`s than `RequestString`s, so my intuition was to first go for the `RequestString` and then backtrack.

I guess I could play with (?<) for lookbehind, but the lengths between `ConnectionString`s and `RequestString`s are essentially arbitrary -- will that work well?

Comment: Please show a sample file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Find and number all RequestStrings, then loop through them
grep -n RequestString file | while IFS=":" read n string; do
   echo $n,$string    # Debug
   head -n $n file | tail -r | grep -m1 Connection
done
```

**Output**

```
4,RequestString 1
6189:Connection
7,RequestString 2
7230:Connection
9,RequestString 3
8280:Connection
```

with this input file

```
6189:Connection

RequestString 1
7229:Connection
7230:Connection
RequestString 2
8280:Connection
RequestString 3
```

**Note**: I used `tail -r` because OSX lacks `tac` which I would have preferred.

Comment: The `RequestString` contains the pid which is used to match the latest Connection line before the request line.

Comment: It'll be in my variable called `string` so you can parse it out easily enough - either in the initial `grep` using `-o` option, or within the loop using bash parameter subsitution...http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: I've been meaning to try out a lookbehind regex to do this, that's the cause of delay. I guess I could accept your answer till then, and reconsider the best solution when I have something.